# Use of Telerik Controls does it impact to my application performance?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

Use of third party component does affect the performance of the application. 
I am writing MVC.Net application with the help of Telerik extension. 
Also What will be the best practice to write a mvc application in terms of performance and maintainability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think anything using that many rows is going to be impacted.

I'd recommend writing a very simple app that loads the records using Telerik, and time it with a `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`. Do the same thing with the alternative method you were considering, and compare the times. For example:

```
var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
// Simulate long-running operation
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
Console.Write(sw.Elapsed);
```

If you break down the task (e.g. fetching the data and displaying the data), and time each part, it may be that Telerik is better at one than the other.

Comment: Do you have any sample code (example) ?